# Relation between fractional and integer Sobolev norms

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I encountered a situation where I have to add two norms defined on the boundary:

$$C_1 ||u||^2_{L_2(\partial\Omega)} + C_2 ||u||^2_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)},$$

but do not really know how to manipulate this expression. Is there a relation between the norms?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a trivial relation $\|u\|_{L_2}\leq\|u\|_{H^1}$
2. The Sobolev embedding theorem as well as other similar results may give you some tools to use to relate Sobolev norms to $L_p$ norms and other Sobolev norms. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg%E2%80%93Sobolev_inequality) or chapter 5 of Evans for more details.
3. The generalized Hölder inequality (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H%C3%B6lder's_inequality)) may also prove useful if you can bound the Sobolev norm in terms of some $L_p$ norm. Assuming your boundary is compact, you can take the 2 functions in the inequality to be $1$ and $u$, obtaining bounds between different $L_p$ norms with a constant depending on $\partial\Omega$.

Without knowing more about what you are trying to show it's hard to know exactly which sort of inequalities you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Regarding 1: how is then $||u||_{H^1}$ related to $||u||_{H^{3/2}}$?
We can assume that $\partial \Omega \in C^{1,1}$. I would like to bound the sum from above, preferably such that:
$$C_1 ||u||^2_{L_2(\partial\Omega)} + C_2 ||u||^2_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq C_3 C_1 ||u||^2_{L_2(\partial\Omega)}.$$

Comment: whpowell96 I found that the fractional norm on the boundary is defined as (Brenner, Scott pp. 195): 
$$||v||^2_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)} = ||v||^2_{L^2(\partial\Omega)} + |v|^2_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}$$
I think that I could work with this type of equality, but it should involve the 3/2 norm, not the 1/2 norm.

Comment: I'm not sure that a bound of the kind you are looking for even exists. You can make $\|u\|_{H^{3/2}}$ arbitrarily large without changing $\|u\|_{L^2}$

Comment: Is the 3/2 norm then defined as:
$$ ||v||^2_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)} = ||v||^2_{L_2(\partial \Omega)} + |v|^2_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)} + |v|^2_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)} ?$$

Comment: Your definition of the $H^{3/2}$ norm seems to be circular. Typically fractional Sobolev spaces (with $p=1$) are defined in terms of either the Fourier transform or some sort of singular integral. You can make the $H^{3/2}$ norm arbitrarily large while keeping the $L^2$ norm constant by considering a sequence of functions like, say, $f_n = \sin(nx)$

Comment: Here is a good introduction to the topic https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/